# Setting php encoding for v.7.2

Tags: character-encoding, php-7.2

Today I made a (failed) upgrade from php 7.0 t0 7.2 and I noticed this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding()
```

Is there sth equivalent in php 7.2 to set in my code?

Comment: Current setting: \mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: I don't want to compile sources but use Ubuntu 16 source packages by adding repository "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php". What are my options there?

Comment: You probably want to install `php7.2-mbstring` then. If that's not it, try asking specifically at https://askubuntu.com or http://serverfault.com.